# Dynamically generated content in a PlaceHolder inside of a FormView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, formview

Reaching out for some help here, as this has me stumped.  Long story short, I've got a dynamic Table that is built from Functions, displayed in a Placeholder inside a FormView.

I have a 'save' button inside the EditItemTemplate of the FormView, CommandName="Save" - I have a Select Case (using VB here) and (almost) everything is working as expected.

However, when I pull my PlaceHolder in Code Behind, I'm showing no controls in the PlaceHolder.

Here's a brief rundown:

FormView ItemTemplate has a View_PlaceHolder that shows data from dynamically generated table correctly.
FormView EditItemTemplate has an Edit_PlaceHolder that loads the same Data from dynamically generated table into TextBox (works fine, same data is shown as expected)

When I click Save, my current code is:

```
Dim Edit_PlaceHolder as PlaceHolder = FormView1.FindControl("Edit_FV_PlaceHolder")
Dim EditTable as Table = Edit_PlaceHolder.FindControl("Edit_Plan_Holder")
```

Edit_PlaceHolder is not nothing, but has 0 controls in Controls.Count

Oh, one more bit of information - my Table is built and added to the PlaceHolder in the FormView.DataBound event.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What events are you using, can you show some code?

Comment: Using FormView.DataBound to determine CurrentMode. If CurrentMode = ReadOnly, then show View Table.  If CurrentMode=Edit, show Edit Table.   I add my controls to the PlaceHolder in FormView.DataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

You must repopulate and add the dynamically added table on PostBacks too, not just on the initial load.  Check out the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504777/dynamically-created-checkboxlist-in-placeholder-controls-throwing-null-referen) for more detail.

Comment: At what point in the LifeCycle can I do that?  Page_Load?  Page_Init?

Comment: I've always been able to pull it off in Page_Load, but a lot of what I read says do it in Init.  The big key is to keep that part of the load outside of a If Not Page.IsPostback block.

Comment: Well, this is odd.  Trying that out now.  When I click 'Edit' and set the FormView in CodeBehind to Edit, I show record #1 just fine - but the placeholder control is still the View Placeholder.  If I click to Record 2, then the Edit Placeholder shows up in the controls.  It's almost like I'm seeing this cycle: 1) Initial Page Load - loads FormView VIEW data. 2) Click Edit Button, causes postback, Page_Load is triggered again, FormView at THIS point still shows View, and FormView's databind and switch to EDIT is not fired until AFTER Page_Load completes.

Comment: Well, I built a little function to iterate recursively through the child controls of a parent control I pass it.  If I run this function AFTER FormView.DataBound I show the proper Edit_Placeholder I"m looking for, and further - all my controls are in it.  After I click the Save button, however, I have *zero* controls in the PlaceHolder.  My controls inside the PlaceHolder (which is inside the FormView) are being lost when I click a button.  How do I save that data across the click?

Comment: I would refer back to my answer.  Make sure every control is re-added on every postback for those values to persist.

Comment: How do I add a control back into a FormView on Page_load?  More specifically, the data I need isn't loaded until the FormView.DataBound, which occurs AFTER Page_Load.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's what was happening:

1) As NoAlias stated, need to keep the ID's.  I used Page_Load to set a ViewState variable if I was in 'view' or 'edit' mode.

2) I used a separate BuildViewTable() method and BuildEditTable() method, and inside those called my separate class and constructed the table.

3) It's all working now :)  Thanks, NoAlias!